# RenderScript blur overrides the original Bitmap

Tags: java, android, bitmap, blur, renderscript

I am trying to use **RenderScript** to create a blurred bitmap to set it as a background for a *LinearLayout* which contains an *ImageView*. I also want a clear original copy of the bitmap so that I can set it as an image in the *ImageView*.

Here's my code:

```
ImageView mainImage;

Bitmap mainBMP, blurredBMP

LinearLayout background;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_work_area);

    getImage(); // obtain bitmap from file
    mainImage.setImageBitmap(mainBMP); // set the original bitmap in imageview 

    // create a blurred bitmap drawable and set it as background for linearlayout
    BitmapDrawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), blur(mainBMP)); 
    mainBackground.setBackground(drawable); 


    registerForContextMenu(objectImage);
    registerForContextMenu(textArea);

}

private void getImage(){
    String filename = getIntent().getStringExtra("image");
    try {
        FileInputStream is = this.openFileInput(filename);
        mainBMP = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        is.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@TargetApi(17)
public Bitmap blur(Bitmap image) {
    if (null == image) return null;

    Bitmap outputBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(image);
    final RenderScript renderScript = RenderScript.create(this);
    Allocation tmpIn = Allocation.createFromBitmap(renderScript, image);
    Allocation tmpOut = Allocation.createFromBitmap(renderScript, outputBitmap);

    //Intrinsic Gausian blur filter
    ScriptIntrinsicBlur theIntrinsic = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(renderScript, Element.U8_4(renderScript));
    theIntrinsic.setRadius(BLUR_RADIUS);
    theIntrinsic.setInput(tmpIn);
    theIntrinsic.forEach(tmpOut);
    tmpOut.copyTo(outputBitmap);
    return outputBitmap;
}
```

This is how I want the final result to be: 
[image: I want like this.]

But this is what I get: 
[image: I dont want this]

So how do I make **two copies** of the same bitmap in which one of them is **blurred** and the other is **clear and original**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is with how the output bitmap is being created.  You're using a call that gives you an immutable `Bitmap` object based on an input `Bitmap` object.  Change this line:

```
Bitmap outputBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(image);
```

to be this:

```
Bitmap outputBitmap = image.copy(image.getConfig(), true);
```

That will give you a separate `Bitmap` object which is a copy of the original and mutable.  Right now Renderscript is really modifying the original (though it really should fail because the `outputBitmap` was immutable.

Comment: That did it! Thanks.

Comment: Great, glad to hear it!

Comment: What about when the first bitmap was not created from a picture? Mine comes from `decodeStream`

Comment: @hippietrail it shouldn't matter.  The resultant `Bitmap` (as long as it is valid) will have its configuration set correctly by the bitmap factory.  As long as your RS understands this input and is expecting to produce the same type of output (width/height, bits per pixel, etc.) then you should be able to use this same technique.